# Subdifferential of normal cone proof

Tags: convex-optimization, differential, convex-cone

**Problem:**
I'm stuck showing the opposite direction. I wanna show that  $N(x̄,Ω)=∂δΩ(x̄)$ subdifferential of normal cone, where $N(x̄,Ω)=\{g \in Rn | \langle g, z-x̄\rangle ≤ 0, ∀ z ∈ Ω\}$.

**My attempt:**

First direction $∂δΩ(x̄) ⊂ N(x̄,Ω)$:

Let's take $g ∈ ∂δΩ(x̄)$ then

$$\langle g, z-x̄\rangle ≤ δΩ(z) - δΩ(x̄), ∀z ∈ Rn \,\text{ and }\, δΩ(x̄)=0\, \text{ since }\, x̄ ∈ Ω.$$ Hence

$$\langle g, z-x̄ \rangle ≤ δΩ(z), ∀z ∈ Rn$$. Also $∀z ∈ Rn ⇒ ∀ z ∈ Ω ⇒ δΩ(z)=0.$ Therefore

$$\langle g, z-x̄\rangle ≤ 0 , ∀ z ∈ Ω  ⇒  g ∈ N(x̄,Ω).$$ In opposite direction we have to show that $N(x̄,Ω) ⊂ ∂δΩ(x̄)$.

My problem is starting here because I don't know how I can start to prove other side. If you have any idea please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn [how to type math formulas](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, please clearly define all the used notation. For example, not all readers are familiar with the notation $\delta_{\Omega}$ for the indicator function of a set $\Omega$.

Back to the question. The results follow directly from the definitions of the normal cone and the subdiferential. Just write down the subdiferential using the definition and simplify it:
\begin{align}
\partial \delta_{\Omega}(x) &= \left\{g\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid \langle g, z - x \rangle \le \delta_{\Omega}(z) - \delta_{\Omega}(x) \ \forall z\in\mathbb{R}^n\right\}\\
&=
\begin{cases}
\emptyset &\mbox{if }x\not\in\Omega\\
\left\{g\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid \langle g, z - x \rangle \le \delta_{\Omega}(z) \ \forall z\in\mathbb{R}^n\right\} &\mbox{if }x\in\Omega
\end{cases}\\
&=
\begin{cases}
\emptyset &\mbox{if }x\not\in\Omega\\
\left\{g\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid \langle g, z - x \rangle \le \delta_{\Omega}(z)\ \forall z\in\Omega\right\} &\mbox{if }x\in\Omega
\end{cases}
\end{align}
which is precisely the definition of the normal cone $N_{\Omega}(x)$.

Comment: When ı write this problem  ı had only few minitues so ım sorry if it seems complicated for you. This is the direction that I had already shown. I wanna go from NΩ(x) to ∂δΩ(x). Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: @mathstudent Are you saying that if we have $a=b=c=d$, then we still cannot conclude that $d=a$?

Comment: eyvallah kanka xd

Comment: @mathstudent You are welcome. You should upvote and accept the answer.